# How to add a new sortable date meta to a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

Looking for a point in the right direction, i've been working on an events plugin for a site, quite a simple plugin, adds a custom post type called events, adds some custom taxonomies, used ACF to add the fields to the CPT.

But I need to add 'start date and time', and 'end date and time' fields to it in a way that I'll be able to sort by start date/time in the admin side, and be able to sort by them when I query the posts as well.

I thought I might be able to do this with the ACF date/time field, but it's just not playing ball. Any ideas?

Comment: Which event plugin you are using? I think the basic event plugin contains start and end date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm understanding correctly, you want to sort your results by a meta value right? that meta value being the date/time field. In your loop, you may want to try out something along the lines of:

```
$your_custom_query = new WP_Query( array(
'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        'date_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'date_time_meta_key_here',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        )
    ),
    'orderby'    => 'date_clause'
));
```

See the original wordpress documentation here for more info: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/